# Eclipse Ditto enable AMQP 1.0 connection fails

Tags: amqp, eclipse-ditto

I was trying to enable the AMQP 1.0 connection with Ditto running on my local virtual Ubuntu machine following the instruction from the website. So I created the twin on my instance, verified it exists and the following step was to create a connection with the endpoint.

**First my question:** Is it mandatory to use Hono to create AMQP connection? Cause I would prefer to use simple mosquito client. So I tryed to execute the PUT CURL:

```
{ 
  "targetActorSelection": "/system/sharding/connection", 
  "headers": { "aggregate": false }, 
  "piggybackCommand": { 
    "type": "connectivity.commands:createConnection",
    "connection": {} 
  }
}
```

to the adress where my instance of eclipse ditto running http://localhost/devops/piggyback/connectivity, but i'm getting 401 Authorization error. 
I tryed to put the basic authentication used in the example: devops:devopsPw1!, but it fails as well.

Meanwhile sending the same command to the Ditto sandbox instance working fine. What did I miss in my configuration?

Thanks a lot in advance, Mila

Answer (score 2):

regarding the first question. No it is not mandatory to use Hono to create an AMQP connection. You can establish an AMQP connection to whatever uri you define in your connection.
This leads me to the next point. The JSON you provided in your question is missing the description of the actual connection.
I see that we should clarify this in the documentation more explicitly like we did for the [testConnection command](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/connectivity-manage-connections.html#test-connection).
You could have a look at the [connection model](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-connections.html#connection-model) to see how to configure the connection.

Regarding your second question (401 response) the problem is that the default devops password is "foobar". You can configure it to a password you like by setting the environment variable `DEVOPS_PASSWORD` of the gateway container.

I hope I could help you.